# Why 'Row' changes to 'row' in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, row, rows, vba

For unknow reason my Excel VBA editor changes:
`Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = MyString`
into
`Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1).Value = MyString`

Word "Row" should start with capital "R" but after I type it, it changes to small "r". I have checked the code and I am sure I do not use "raw" as a variable. The macro itself works fine as if it was written "Row". On other workbooks everything is ok (R is capitalized).

Anybody has idea why it happens?

Comment: Similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425541/vba-automatically-changing-range-to-range/27425753#27425753)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used variable `row` in VBA of that worksheet. Then I changed the name of the variable `row` to something else like `MyRowName` Although there was no such variable as `row` in VBA anymore, it still kept lower case for that word. As I mentioned above everything worked fine i.e. `ActiveCell.row` returned what it should for `ActiveCell.Row`.

For just aesthetic reasons, I have copied the whole VBA to another worksheet and the bug was crunched. Row returned to Upper case.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting a bit tired of from looking where exactly I have declared a Row with a small letter, as far as it was not declared anywhere.

Thus, found a great solution - add the following in a module:

```
Public Sub TestMe
   Dim Row as Long
End Sub
```

And see the whole code changing. Then you may delete it. Or simply write `Dim Row as Long` on a new line, somewhere in your code. And then delete it.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to add it as a `Sub`, simply adding `Dim Row as Long` within the `Sub`/`Function` and then removing it does the trick! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Idlehands, you are welcome! :) Indeed, adding `Dim Row as Long` would be enough, even outside Sub or Function :)

Answer (score 2):

VBA isn't case sensitive, so I wouldn't lose too much sleep over it.  The editor tries to convert all of the variable cases to however it was dimmed.  Most likely the ActiveCell definition was screwed up somehow.