# Excel Selecting a Row

Tags: vba, excel

I am Trying to create a macro that will take the 1st Cell of a selection and merge it with the 6th Cell. I am getting error 400.

```
Sub SignPage()
Dim ws As Worksheet, BasePoint As Range, row As Long, singlecell As Long, 
singleCol As Long, sLong As Long, sShort As String
Set BasePoint = Selection
row = BasePoint.row
Range(Cells(row, BasePoint.Columns(1)), Cells(row, BasePoint.Columns(6))).Merge

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you should refer to the first column of Basepoint and take its column. This could be achieved, if you amend your line like to this:

```
Range(Cells(row,BasePoint.Columns(1).Column),Cells(row,BasePoint.Columns(6).Column)).Merge
```

As an advice:

- do not use names like `row`, `column`, `Cells`, `Range` etc. as a variable, the Excel object module library inside `VBA` uses them as well. In your case, you have `BasePoint.row`. If you did not have the variable `row`, then the VBEditor would have written `BasePoint.Row` automatically.
- try to avoid `Selection`, although it depends on the context - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
- as @Mat's Mug mentioned in the comments, it is a good habit to show the "parent" of `Cells` and `Ranges`, when you are using them.
  Thus in your case, something like this:

---

```
With Worksheets(1)
       .Range(.Cells(row, BP.Columns(1).Column), .Cells(row, BP.Columns(6).Column)).Merge
End With
```

Then it would always refer to the first worksheet (or whichever you need to) and not to the `ActiveSheet`, which would be referred, if the `Parent` in not mentioned. (I have written `BP` instead of `BasePoint` to make sure it goes on one line.)

Comment: FWIW there is nothing wrong with `cell`, `row`, `column`, etc.; VBA does not use them at all. VBA isn't the Excel object model, and the Excel object model isn't VBA. Besides there's no `Row` or `Column` or `Cell` global-scope object in the Excel object model. So the worst it can do is make `Range.Row` appear as `Range.row`, which has no impact whatsoever. `row` and `column` (and `cell`) are perfectly fine local variable names, and they're not shadowing anything. The unqualified `Cells` and `Range` calls are much more dangerous of a habit to have.

Comment: Well i am going to be using the selection to know the start column and end column as well as knowing the row. So then i can construct a Sign Page On the Pages i need to. And that selection will be used as the base point to build off.

Comment: @JacobLenertz I expect this code to throw an error if the `Selection` isn't at least 6 columns wide.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - true, but `Range.row` is a perfectly good reason not to use it. The OCD inside me is rebelling. But concerning `VBA` and `Excel Object Module` you are right, it is better to be edited.

Comment: @Vityata FWIW every single `Property Let` and `Property Set` procedure I write takes a `ByVal value As Whatever` parameter. I've gotten used to see `Range.Value` as `Range.value`, and live a happy life ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - with `.Value` and `.value` I can live as well. But `.row` is too much for me. And I am not the only one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570703/why-row-changes-to-row-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 3):

This should be enough:

```
Selection(1).Resize(, 6).Merge
```

Explanation: `Selection` can span several cells, so `Selection(1)` takes the top left cell - thus, we always refer to one cell.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Only missing a type check on `Selection`, and perhaps a cast to `Range` to get IntelliSense, but this won't throw any error if the selection isn't at least 6 columns wide.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, the `Selection` can span several cells, so I edited answer :)